# D3js moving nested groups

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to move nested svg group elements within a group. My requirement is to move the large rectangle along with all the elements in it, But I also need to move the individual groups inside the large rectangle to be moved (only inside the large rectangle). I can move the large group but not the groups inside it. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4aswd2e/) with my work. Can anyone help me?

```
<g id="a" transform="translate(0,0)">
    <g>
        <rect x="10" y="10" width="200" height="200" fill="red"></rect>
        <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="105" fill="blue"></circle>
        <circle r="5" cx="210" cy="105" fill="blue"></circle>
    </g>
    <g id="b" class="e" transform="translate(0,0)">
        <rect x="20" y="20" width="50" height="50" fill="black"></rect>
        <circle r="5" cx="20" cy="45" fill="blue"></circle>
        <circle r="5" cx="70" cy="45" fill="blue"></circle>
    </g>
    <g id="c" class="e" transform="translate(0,0)">
        <rect x="90" y="20" width="50" height="50" fill="black"></rect>
        <circle r="5" cx="90" cy="45" fill="blue"></circle>
        <circle r="5" cx="140" cy="45" fill="blue"></circle>
    </g>
</g>
```

```
<script>
    d3.select('#a').call(d3.behavior.drag().on('drag', function () {
        d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.x + ',' + d3.event.y + ')');
//        d3.event.stopPropagation();

    }));

    d3.selectAll('.e').call(d3.behavior.drag().on('drag', function () {
        d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.x + ',' + d3.event.y + ')');
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
    }));


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a `stopPropagation` on the `dragstart` event of your inner boxes.

```
d3.selectAll('.e').call(d3.behavior.drag()
     .on('dragstart', function () {
         d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
      })
     .on('drag', function () {
     ...
```

Note - to restrict the drag area for the inner boxes, just limit your translate values to > 0 and the maximum size of the parent box (here's a related question - [Explaining Mike Bostock's d3.js dragmove function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009718/explaining-mike-bostocks-d3-js-dragmove-function)).

By the way, if you set the origin for the drag, it won't jump (to align the top left corner with the mouse position) when you start to drag.

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/v9487fhh/

Comment: hey potatopeelings.. no wait.. life saver. :D +2 for the answer man.

Comment: I have set the origin as you said, But can we modify the origin once the element is moved? I mean I want to strat moving from where it is stopped.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768845/d3js-reset-the-origin-of-a-drag-behaviour

Comment: I see you got it answered there. Cheers!

Comment: Yep, Thanks mate. (y)