# D3js reset the origin of a drag behaviour

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to reset the drag behavior of a svg group. My requirement is to move the group from where it was stopped last. Here is my work [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fawzan/9n7mkrfe/). can some on help me?

```
<g id="a" transform="translate(0,0)">
    <g>
        <rect x="10" y="10" width="200" height="200" fill="red"></rect>
        <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="105" fill="blue"></circle>
        <circle r="5" cx="210" cy="105" fill="blue"></circle>
    </g>
    <g id="b" class="e" transform="translate(0,0)">
        <rect x="20" y="20" width="50" height="50" fill="black"></rect>
        <circle r="5" cx="20" cy="45" fill="blue"></circle>
        <circle r="5" cx="70" cy="45" fill="blue"></circle>
    </g>
    <g id="c" class="e" transform="translate(0,0)">
        <rect x="90" y="20" width="50" height="50" fill="black"></rect>
        <circle r="5" cx="90" cy="45" fill="blue"></circle>
        <circle r="5" cx="140" cy="45" fill="blue"></circle>
    </g>
</g>
```

```
<script>
    d3.select('#a').call(d3.behavior.drag().on('drag', function () {
        d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.x + ',' + d3.event.y + ')');
//        d3.event.stopPropagation();

    }));

    d3.selectAll('.e')
            .call(d3.behavior.drag()
                    .origin(function () {
                        var t = d3.select(this);
                        return {x: t.attr("x"), y: t.attr("y")};
                    }
                    )
                    .on('dragstart', function () {
                        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
                    })
                    .on('drag', function () {
                        console.log();
                        d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.x + ',' + d3.event.y + ')');
                    }))
                    .on('dragend', function () {
                        d3.select(this).call(d3.behavior.drag().origin(function () {

                            var t = d3.select(this);
                            return {x: t.attr("x"), y: t.attr("y")};
                        }))
                    })

    ;


</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an origin function to do this. You have to add this before every drag in your SVG.

`.origin(function() { 
            var t = d3.select(this);
            return {x: t.attr("x") + d3.transform(t.attr("transform")).translate[0],
                    y: t.attr("y") + d3.transform(t.attr("transform")).translate[1]};
        })`

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jffasna/qocc589y/)