# How to limit the d3.js drag behavior on a mercator map

Tags: d3.js, svg, limit, drag, mercator

I have implemented a map in a svg-Element with the mercator-function of d3.js.
The Map represented only a specific city - everything outside the city-map is not relevant for my project.

Now I want to implement some function like zoom() and drag() on this map.

But I can not find any solution, to handle the drag()-function with my mercator-map - I can not limit the area of the transformation.
(the user should not be able to drag the map outside the map of the city)

For normal svg-elements this works:

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
                 .on("drag", dragmove);

function dragmove(d) {
    var x = Math.max(0, Math.min('width-of-svg-element', d3.event.x));
    var y = Math.max(0, Math.min('height-of-svg-element', d3.event.y));
    d3.select(this)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
    }
```

But it doesn't work for my mercator-map.

please help me :(

Thanks in advance!

Here is a small example:
https://jsfiddle.net/c55w7u9e/

My intention is, that there should be no possibility for the user to drag the red circle (in this example, but in my project the map) outside the svg element...

Comment: do you have an example you an show ? Preferably on JSFiddle ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c55w7u9e/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatoneguy/c55w7u9e/4/

You werent taking your radius into account. It was working, but you can't see it. Update drag to this :

```
function dragmove(d) {
    var x = Math.max(0, Math.min(width - radius, d3.event.x));
    var y = Math.max(0, Math.min(height - radius, d3.event.y));
    d3.select(this)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
    }
```

Help from this question : [Explaining Mike Bostock's d3.js dragmove function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009718/explaining-mike-bostocks-d3-js-dragmove-function)

And this example : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1557377 //think its offline ...

I would use this function to limit, it works better :

```
function dragmove(d) {
  d3.select(this)
      .attr("cx", d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d3.event.x)))
      .attr("cy", d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d3.event.y)));
        }
```

Updated fiddle from examples : https://jsfiddle.net/thatoneguy/c55w7u9e/5/